# Secondary fetch endpoint with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following viewset:

```
class ProductViewSet(
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ...
```

This provides me with endpoint for fetching a product by ID:

```
/products/{id}
```

I'm trying to add another endpoint for fetching a product with secondary unique key (uuid), so that I will have the following endpoints:

```
# Existing endpoint, lookup by ID. This I have, and want to keep.
/products/{product_id}  

# Additional endpoint, lookup by UUID. This is what I'm trying to add.
/products/uuid/{product_uuid}
```

So API consumer must be able to look up a product by either ID or UUID.

How can I achieve this with DRF? I'm using DRF 3.8.2 and Django 1.11.

Is it somehow possible to make `@action()` decorator provide this? Its basic behaviour does not solve the problem as it only provides urls of pattern `/products/{id}/detail` or `/products/detail`.

Comment: do you want second end point or just second unique key?

Comment: @BearBrown both, please see updated question

Comment: i think the simple way is to use the answer and only add new route to your urls with the same View.

Comment: @BearBrown can you provide a concrete example? If I use the same view, how does it know if it should lookup by ID or UUID?

Comment: if you need it, wait a few hours, sorry, i need do some work)

Answer (score 1):

For multiple lookup you can write mixin:

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin(object):
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs[field]: # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

And use it like this:

```
class ProductViewSet(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, 
            mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
            viewsets.GenericViewSet):
        lookup_fields =( 'product_uuid', 'pk')
```

more details in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins)

Comment: I don't think this will help in **adding** an alternate lookup.

Comment: @anttikoo check updated answer. It uses custom mixin.

Comment: I don't want to modify the existing lookup. When I say "add an alternate lookup" I mean "keep existing + provide another one". Please see updated question, hopefully it's more explicit now.